# Android cannot update table in mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, database

this is my .java

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(“http://*******.com/mobileproject/updateclass.php”);
try {
List nameValuePairsUpdate = new ArrayList(2);
nameValuePairsUpdate.add(new BasicNameValuePair(“code”, aCode[i]));
nameValuePairsUpdate.add(new BasicNameValuePair(“section”, aSection[i]));
nameValuePairsUpdate.add(new BasicNameValuePair(“registered”, Integer.toString(registered)));
nameValuePairsUpdate.add(new BasicNameValuePair(“empty”, Integer.toString(empty)));
nameValuePairsUpdate.add(new BasicNameValuePair(“status”, status));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

and this is my .php

```
mysql_connect(“localhost”,”******”,”********”);
mysql_select_db(“*******”);
$registered = $_POST['registered'];
$empty = $_POST['empty'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$section = $_POST['section'];
mysql_query(“UPDATE Class SET registered = ‘$registered’ , empty = ‘$empty’ , status = ‘$status’ WHERE code = ‘$code’ AND section = ‘$section’”);
```

My problem is when I click the button (code in .java), the registered, empty and status columns (initial they contain values and then) become empty(no value). What I missing here?

Comment: what is `mysql_query` returning? if it's returning false, what does `mysql_error` tell you? (btw, the quotes in your post are a bit strange - probably cut/paste issue though).

Comment: Check the "wire" output from HTTP Client. It will at least show you if the values are being submitted. Else, all looks good on the surface except for your lack of binds on the SQL.

Comment: i dont have much experience in php but i dont think the quotes there are right in the query. maybe double check that. that's not a proper string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to echo/log the string, that you put into mysql_query like:

```
$sql = “UPDATE Class SET registered = ‘$registered’ , empty = ‘$empty’ , status = ‘$status’ WHERE code = ‘$code’ AND section = ‘$section’”;
echo $sql; // or yourowndebuglogfunction($sql);
mysql_query($sql);
```

And then try to run it directly in mysql.